# git merging master into task branch is removing code

Tags: git, merge

I am seeing issues when merging the master into a task branch where code in the master is being removed when merging into the task branch.

Example:
I have multiple developers working on their own branches all of which have a common ancestry from the master.

-Developer A is using branch A

-Developer B is using branch B

-Both developers begin from the same point on the master

-Developer A completes his task first, modifies somfile.c, and a successful merger back to the master is done.

-Developer B wants to obtain the changes to somefile.c by merging the master into branch B.

What I am seeing is that the changes made by developer A to somefile.c (which are now on the master) are being removed when merging the master into branch B.

Can someone help me better understand why code is being removed?  Or point me to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Action by developer B:
git checkout master
git checkout branch B
git merge master

edit: updated title for clarification
edit2: updated format for better viewing

Comment: Please post the exact steps Developer B followed.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here and see if any of it applies in your situation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316326/automerge-issues/26319753#26319753

Answer (score 0):

Developer B has to pull the updated code from remote

Developer B:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout branch B
git merge master
```

Comment: same results.  The line of code in somefile.c has been removed when the master was merged into branch B.